# Calling a php function from a wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to create a link/button inside a wordpress site which starts a plugin if you click on it (in my case it should make a cookie banner appear). I'm completely new to this so I'm not 100% sure which function actually starts the cookie banner but i assume it's `function func_wp_vue()`inside the `main.php`. The main.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    function func_load_vuescripts() {
        wp_register_script('wp_js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'dist/js/app.js', [], '1.0.0', true);
        wp_register_script('wp_js1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'dist/js/chunk-vendors.js', true);
        wp_register_style('wp_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'dist/css/app.css', true);
        wp_register_style('wp_css1', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'dist/css/chunk-vendors.css', true);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'func_load_vuescripts');

    function func_wp_vue(){
        wp_enqueue_script('wp_js');
        wp_enqueue_script('wp_js1');
        wp_enqueue_style('wp_css');
        wp_enqueue_style('wp_css1');

        $str =  "<div id='app'>"
                .""
                ."</div>";
        return $str;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'cookie', 'func_wp_vue' );
```

The plugin is uploaded and loads on the site but i would like to manually activate the cookie banner again if i click on the link/button.
I tried to implement it with`<p><a href="wp-content/plugins/cookie/main.php">Click me</a></p>` into the wordpress site but just get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_action() in /home/www/wordpress-cookie/wp-content/plugins/cookie/main.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/www/wordpress-cookie/wp-content/plugins/cookie/main.php on line 16

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you are on a pretty wrong path already. _“which starts a plugin if you click on it”_ doesn’t even begin to make much sense, plugins aren’t “started”. The code you have shown adds JavaScript to the page output, and that is likely not the part you should be messing with to begin with here. Hiding the banner presumably happens by calling some JavaScript function on the client side, and that probably has a counterpart to show it again. If so, that JS function is what you should call when your button gets clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The app.js file has over 2k lines of code and I'm completely new to javascript. Any hint which keywords inside the app.js I should look for? The banner loads once you enter the page so there has to be a function to show it  I assume.

Comment: Looking in one of the script files that the above code adds might be a good start.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these can be found inside the app.js file. Only 'cookie', which is the shortcode to add the cookie banner on the website. Is it possible the function is related to the shortcode?

Comment: Little point in guessing, especially for us here, as we only know what you have shown us so far. Does that plugin you are using not have any sort of developer documentation?

Comment: Sadly there is no documentation and I can't contact the developer of the plugin. Guess I have to go through all the code and try to find something. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Does the plugin show cookie banner? That is, You use a plugin for cookie banner?